# Small bug when I resize image proportionally using jquery.

Tags: jquery, image, jsp, resize

( 10 reputation for showing images??... really?...)

Hi guys.

The problem I'm undergoing is that,

```
when I resize images, they are resized more than once I believe.
```

For example,

```
I uploaded a square image, but the result is rectangle.
```

When the wrong result comes, I refresh the page with F5 key, and they look square.

only height og the resized image is the problem.

Below is the code I used to resize those images.

```
function thumbnail_resize(obj) {
    var maxW = 50;      var maxH = 50;
    var wid = obj.width();
    var hei = obj.height();

    if( wid > maxW ) {
        hei *= (maxW / wid);
        wid = maxW;
    }
    if( hei > maxH ) {
        wid *= (maxH / hei);
        hei = maxH;
    }
    obj.attr('width', wid);
    obj.attr('height', hei);

    delete maxW, maxH, wid, hei;
    return;
}
```

Currently I believe the resizing ratio ( i.e => hei *= maxW / wid; ) is applied several times when resizing the height of those images.

Please give me some wisedom!!!

Comment: There is no reason to use `delete` on your local variables.  That's just wasted code.  Worth reading this: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: Are you sure that your images have finished loading BEFORE you measure them and resize them?  Do you know that if you only size one dimension (width or height), the browser will automatically size the other dimesion to maintain the original aspect ratio?  When is `thumbnail_resize()` called?

Comment: @jfriend00 I read other question. One of them suggested delete.
I erased it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I called that thumbnail_resize() in the $(document).ready( function() { // here }).
And, YES I know the automatical sizing for the other dimension. I used that code because I wanted to make sure both width and height are under 50px.
If an image is 100px * 200px, I resize only its width, then the image becomes 50px * 100px, the height is still over 50px.
Thanks

Comment: If that's the case, then check to see which side is larger before doing the resize:

`if (wid > hei) { if( wid > maxW ) { hei *= (maxW / wid); wid = maxW; } } else { if( hei > maxH ) { wid *= (maxH / hei); hei = maxH;
 } }`

Comment: If you're doing this on `$(document).ready()`, then some of your images are probably not loaded yet.  You need to do it on `$(window).load()` if you want all images loaded.  Also, still don't have to set both dimensions.  Just set the larger one to the max size you want.

Comment: @JamieBarker
I modified my code as you suggested.
Thank you for the tip~^^

Comment: @jfriend00

I moved the thumbnail_resize() call into the $(window).load( function() {// here}) and it worked!! I really appreciate your advice^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that part of your problem is that you are looking at the image's height and width in `$(document).ready()` and the images may not all be loaded yet which means their height and width may not yet be valid.  When you hit reload, the images will come from the browser cache and they will be loaded much faster and thus they may actually be ready in `$(document).ready()` after the reload.

If these images are all in the original HTML of your page (and not inserted dynamically), then you can trigger your resize function with `$(window).load()` instead and the images will all be loaded when that triggers.

In addition, you can constrain your setting of the height and width to only the longest side - you don't have to set both.  Setting just one dimension will allow the browser to resize the other and maintain the original aspect ratio.  If your max height and max width are the same, it can be as simple as this:

```
function thumbnail_resize(obj) {
    var maxDimension = 50;
    var width = obj.width();
    var height = obj.height();
    // if either dimension is too big, then make the longer one smaller
    if (Math.max(width, height) > maxDimension) {
        if (height > width) {
            obj.height(maxDimension);
        } else {
            obj.width(maxDimension);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you want to keep aspect ratio, you don't need to apply height and width at the same time:

```
function thumbnail_resize(obj) {
    var maxW = 50;      var maxH = 50;
    var wid = obj.width();
    var hei = obj.height();

    if ( wid > hei ) {
       if( wid > maxW ) {
            obj.attr('width', maxW);
       }
    } else {
        if( hei > maxH ) {
            obj.attr('height', maxH);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

You should see this [article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images/) about image loading and manipulating them on load. You can't simply expect it to work on document.ready, *especially* in IE.

Comment: Thank you for the article. I've just read it now^^ It's very helpful to me~